# Induction with fractions and exponents

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing, induction, exponentiation, fractions

I need to prove by mathematical induction:

$$ \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2^2} + ... + \frac{1}{2^n} = 1 - \frac{1}{2^n} .$$

My base case is: Assume $n = 1$

$$ \frac{1}{2} = 1 - \frac{1}{2^1} = 1 - \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2} .$$

My inductive hypothesis is: Assume $n = k$

$$ \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2^2} + ... + \frac{1}{2^k} = 1 - \frac{1}{2^k} .$$

we show K+1 is true
$$ \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2^2} +... + \frac{1}{2^k} + \frac{1}{2^{k+1}} = 1 - \frac{1}{2^{k+1}} .$$ 
we know 
$$ \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2^2} +... + \frac{1}{2^k} = 1 - \frac{1}{2^k} .$$
so
$$ 1 - \frac{1}{2^k} + \frac{1}{2^{k+1}} = 1 - \frac{1}{2^{k+1}} .$$
then i go on to manipulate the expression by 
$$ 1  -\frac{1*2}{2^{k}*2} + \frac{1}{2^{k+1}} = 1 - \frac{1}{2^{k+1}} .$$
$$ 1 \frac{-2}{2^{k+1}} + \frac{1}{2^{k+1}} = 1 - \frac{1}{2^{k+1}} .$$
$$ 1 \frac{-2+1}{2^{k+1}} = 1 - \frac{1}{2^{k+1}} .$$
$$ 1 - \frac{1}{2^{k+1}} = 1 - \frac{1}{2^{k+1}} .$$

Update on final stage. Would this make more sense?  I am getting very confused on how to manipulate these fractions.

$$ 1  -\frac{1*2}{2^{k}*2} + \frac{1}{2^{k+1}} = 1 - \frac{1}{2^{k+1}} .$$
$$ 1 -\frac{2}{2^{k+1}} + \frac{1}{2^{k+1}} = 1 - \frac{1}{2^{k+1}} .$$
$$ 1 - \frac{1}{2^{k+1}} = 1 - \frac{1}{2^{k+1}} .$$

but i dont think last bit is right. I'm not sure if i should swau the minus sign to the numerator when trying to multiply by 2 to make it so there is a common denominator I dont think i am manipulating the exponents in the denominator correctly.  Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Please format your question using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). I've edited the first few rows so you can take a look and see how it works, please update the rest of your question so it's easier to read and understand your logic.

Comment: $$\frac 12 + \frac 1{2^2} + ..... + \frac 1{2^k} = 1- \frac 1{2^k}\text{ so}\\\frac 12 + \frac 1{2^2} + ..... + \frac 1{2^k} +\color{red}{\frac 1{2^{k+1}}} = 1- \frac 1{2^k}+\color{red}{\frac 1{2^{k+1}}}$$.  "so
1 - 1/2^(k) + 1/2^(k+1) = 1 - 1/2^(k+1)"....  If that is true you are done.

Comment: In the third line from the bottom, did you mean to write $1 - \frac{2}{2^{k + 1}} + \frac{1}{2^{k + 1}} = 1 - \frac{1}{2^{k + 1}}$?  The second line from the bottom is also unclear.

Comment: yes i did do that on purpose as I know $$ - \frac {2}{2^{k+1}} .$$ is equivalent to $$ \frac {-2}{2^{k+1}}  .$$  I can edit it though if it makes more sense

Answer (score 1):

Induction: Assume $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{2^k}=1-\frac{1}{2^n}$ then $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{1}{2^k}=1-\frac{1}{2^n}+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}=1-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$.